# Select 'item' 2 on load - Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Hello I am just wondering how I can select the second item when the page has loaded?

For example Owl Carousel usually starts on the first item and then displays the next item after that within the HTML structure however when the page loads I'd like it to display the second item class in the HTML below:

```
<div class="full-screen-slider">
    <div id="banner-slider-demo-1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-middle-narrow owl-banner-carousel">
        <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;">
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;">
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;">
        </div>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
           $("#banner-slider-demo-1").owlCarousel({stopOnHover: true,pagination: true, autoPlay: false,navigation: false,paginationSpeed : 500,singleItem:true,});
        });

    </script>
</div>
```

Is there any way that I can do this with Owl Carousel?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the event "owl.jumpTo" or "owl.goTo"

```
jQuery(function($){
       var carousel = $("#banner-slider-demo-1");
       carousel.owlCarousel({stopOnHover: true,pagination: true, autoPlay: false,navigation: false,paginationSpeed : 500,singleItem:true,});
       carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 2) 
    });
```

"owl.goTo" will go straight to the index you give it.
"owl.jumpTo" will animate the carousel to the required index.

Comment: Thanks that works awesome! When the page loads it seems to use the animating for some reason though: dev.drivencarsales.co.uk/#

Comment: any workaround to set start position instead of jumping?

Answer (score 6):

For Owl Carousel 2, use the `to.owl.carousel` event:

```
carousel.trigger('to.owl.carousel', index);
```

Comment: Why this answer is not accepted because this is working fine and the accepted one is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

In OwlCarousel 2 the event has been renamed.

The first parameter is position the second is speed:

```js
carousel.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [2, 300]);
```

You can find more information [in the official documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html).